# Cannot install anything due to libmlt++7 (>= 7.4.0) broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I'm not an expert Linux user and I'm facing a problem that blocks me from installing software.

When I try to install something, I always get:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to fix this.
The following packages have unsatisfied dependencies:
 kdenlive : Depends: libmlt++7 (>= 7.4.0) but won't install
 libmlt7 : Depends: libmlt++7 (>= 7.4.0) but won't install
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' without any packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run `apt --fix-broken install` I get:

```
dpkg: error processing file /var/cache/apt/archives/libmlt++7_7.4.0-1+20.04+focal+release+build18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmlt++-7.so.7' which is also in the libmlt++-7-7 7.0.1-0xneon+20.04+focal+release+build13 package
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmlt++7_7.4.[0-1+20.04+focal+release+build18_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm really lost here and stuck. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Note: It's still in *alpha* with *beta-freeze* reached on 28-March, and *beta* release scheduled for 31-March-2022   *You didn't provide release details; but package versions match jammy*

Comment: I the meanwhile I manage to solve the problem.

Comment: I the meanwhile I managed to solve the problem.  I went to https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libmlt7/download and added deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main.  After that I was able to solve the problem